# web3.eth.personal.ecRecover return wrong address

Tags: web3js, metamask, signature

I'm signing EIP712 message in my front-end app. But when I use web3js.ecrecover to verify address signer it return a wrong address (random).

Data to sign (EIP712) :

```
 msgParams = {
      domain: {
        name: "Project",
        chainId: chainId,
        verifyingContract: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
      },
      message: {
        Maker:addressMetamask2,
    Taker :"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    MakerWei:100000000000000,
    MakerIds:[111],
    TakerWei:0,
    TakerIds:[],
    Expiry:1625174589,
    Salt:1234567,
      },
      primaryType: 'Mail',
      types: {
        EIP712Domain: [
        { name: "name", type: "string" },
        { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" }
        ],
        Mail: [
        { name: "Maker", type: "address" },
        { name: "Taker", type: "address" },
        { name: "MakerWei", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "MakerIds", type: "uint256[]" },
        { name: "TakerWei", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "TakerIds", type: "uint256[]" },
        { name: "Expiry", type: "uint256" },
        { name: "Salt", type: "uint32" },
        ],
      },
    }
```

JSON.stringify data :

```
{"domain":{"name":"Project","chainId":3,"verifyingContract":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"message":{"Maker":"0xdb596f82563f69202a4f1410442c20e5d5ba2910","Taker":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","MakerWei":100000000000000,"MakerIds":[111],"TakerWei":0,"TakerIds":[],"Expiry":1625174589,"Salt":1234567},"primaryType":"Mail","types":{"EIP712Domain":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"chainId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"verifyingContract","type":"address"}],"Mail":[{"name":"Maker","type":"address"},{"name":"Taker","type":"address"},{"name":"MakerWei","type":"uint256"},{"name":"MakerIds","type":"uint256[]"},{"name":"TakerWei","type":"uint256"},{"name":"TakerIds","type":"uint256[]"},{"name":"Expiry","type":"uint256"},{"name":"Salt","type":"uint32"}]}}
```

So I sign with my address 0xdb596f82563f69202a4f1410442c20e5d5ba2910 like this using MetaMask :

```
signTypedDataV4.onclick = async () => {

    try {

      const account = await getCurrentAccount();
      const sign = await ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_signTypedData_v4',
        params: [addressMetamask2, JSON.stringify(msgParams)],
      })
      console.log(sign);

    } catch (err) {
      //todo
    }
  }
```

Sig :

```
0x3ea907ba73bd978d6e5d40bfbfa98c78a1f13d983be97264f89255c24093c8eb7b3e0ba786e9e4648703e7c80495ca65e4f7f2e89383382ed1f3685fd722ea2f1c
```

Then verify :

```
web3.eth.personal.ecRecover(msgParams, sign).then(console.log);
```

***But return "0x5d128d9e19021130e2c69988e54d6a21e94fc9ca" ?***

A correct signature with MyEtherWallet :

```
{
  "address": "0xdb596f82563f69202a4f1410442c20e5d5ba2910",
  "msg": "{\"domain\":{\"name\":\"Project\",\"chainId\":3,\"verifyingContract\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"},\"message\":{\"Maker\":\"0xdb596f82563f69202a4f1410442c20e5d5ba2910\",\"Taker\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",\"MakerWei\":100000000000000,\"MakerIds\":[111],\"TakerWei\":0,\"TakerIds\":[],\"Expiry\":1625174589,\"Salt\":1234567},\"primaryType\":\"Mail\",\"types\":{\"EIP712Domain\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"chainId\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"verifyingContract\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"Mail\":[{\"name\":\"Maker\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"Taker\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"name\":\"MakerWei\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"MakerIds\",\"type\":\"uint256[]\"},{\"name\":\"TakerWei\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"TakerIds\",\"type\":\"uint256[]\"},{\"name\":\"Expiry\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"name\":\"Salt\",\"type\":\"uint32\"}]}}",
  "sig": "0x7dc838cffe46145660e6684f7be7a4e84b8b14563dd14814303eab15dbf6bfda170b213ec12842cf9213f11ed304214237685d830d2a8a9f07eb9cf4d682159e1b",
  "version": "3",
  "signer": "MEW"
}
```

Nota : MyEtherWallet convert "msg" as hex before signature.

What is wrong with web3JS ?

Comment: Using ecRecover is not enough, you can use [eth-sig-util](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util)'s `recoverTypedSignature_V4`.